Insert HTML Table Below Featured Image in Certain Catagory Posts in Wordpress
I am trying to display a table below the feature image in a certain post category.  What I want to do is add create a separate PHP file that would display the table below (simplified version) into the post right below the featured image in said post automatically, but only in certain categories.
The two questions I have as follows..

Put the table into its own PHP file called stats-chaselogs.php

When I create a new post in the parent category I am posting to, the post would automatically add that php file (like a header/footer) into the part of the post between the featured image and the content body area.  How would I script it so that would happen?


Below is the simplified table
    <table width="100%" border="3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GENERAL</td>
      <td>MARGINAL</td>
      <td>SLIGHT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ENHANCED</td>
      <td>MODERATE</td>
      <td>HIGH</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Thank you in advance!
Currently, I have the table in the original post and I am currently copying that post to create new ones with that template.

Use the WordPress Hierarchies file name like  category-{slug}.php and design as you want. this will only event the categories with the slug matching file name.. more here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
